# Why can python webapps keep sessions between restart and not java?

Tags: java, python, web-applications, session

I've used both webapp2 + GAE for python and a number of Java/JEE webapp frameworks. The python WSGI framework could keep users logged in while I redeploy the app while none of the Java web framework that I tried could do it. If I redeploy, users of the Java webapp will get logged out but if I use GAE for python then a redeployment doesn't log users out. Is this a general "feature" of python vs Java webapps and is this true in general or just a coincidence that the ones I tried had these features? Is there a name for this feature, ability to keep users logged in between redeployments and also keeping caches (e.g. memcache) without getting the cache erased for updating the app=

Comment: then java keeps it in ram while python probably used the DB to keep session keys

Comment: Python frameworks generally use cryptographically signed cookies with a timestamp and the username. These don't require *any* serverside resource other than a server-side secret and the user account. Presumably the Java frameworks require a RAM-backed session store instead, and restarting invalidates the sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking hard enough. Pretty much all java servers that I know of are able to persist sessions. Its just a case of reading the docs and setting up the config.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834330/how-do-you-persist-a-tomcat-session) for tomcat.